# Python - socketio import error

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal, socket.io

I installed python-socketio by this command :

```
sudo apt-get install python-socketio
```

But when I want to import it in my program, it has some error :

```
>>> from socketio import SocketIO
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from socketio import SocketIO
ImportError: No module named 'socketio'
```

What is the problem and how can I solve it ?

Comment: I install `python-socketio` using `pip` and there is no problem

Comment: @Arman what was your command ?

Comment: `pip install python-socketio`

Comment: You have conflicting information. What command did you use from the question you used apt here you used pip?

Comment: I use idle2 instead idle3 and my problem solved, thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to install socketio you have to use pip.

I like to use python 3 so I use this command in Ubuntu.

```
sudo -H pip3 install python-socketio
```

If you want to use default python which is probably set as to python2 use.

```
sudo -H pip install python-socketio
```

Also if you type **pip** and then hit tab twice in a row it will show all the different version you have available. For example my output looks like this.

```
pip         pip2        pip2.7      pip3        pip3.5      pip-review
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code can be used ::

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python-socketio
```